# How can I remove scraps of food from books?

Tags: cleaning, paper, books

Sometimes I read books while eating, then scraps of food, such as fragments of biscuits will come into books, too internal to be removed easily. I usually use pencils to push them out, but after that a few scraps are still there and it leaves a pencil stripe on the book.

I want to learn a better way to clean the scraps. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Blow on it...? Or don't eat over top of your books. Or use a pointy thing that isn't a pencil...

Comment: @CaptainObvious I don't know how to describe, but usually scraps goes to the innermost place, where two pages connect.

Comment: Have you tried not eating over top of your books? I read while I eat too, I put the book off to the side. Food doesn't fly over there unless I eat like a wild animal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple toothpick or a dental pick

[image: dental pick]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a [gas duster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_duster)/keyboard cleaner? It would be good for crumbs but probably not as effective on things that would adhere to the pages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this comment. It's something I haven't heard of before.

Answer (score 0):

Just tap the book on the table a few times then dust off anything that remains with the nearest napkin (or blow on it with the built-in can of compressed air in your chest).

Another thing you could try is not eating over top of your books. I read while I eat too and I put the book off to the side. Food doesn't fly over there unless I eat like a wild animal.

If you're eating *exceptionally* messy food, like a rack of BBQ ribs, or a whole turkey leg, or spaghetti with your hands, or live squirrels, just don't read while you eat (or accept that you'll trash what you're reading).

You could also save up and buy a Kindle or something.

And I hate to point out the obvious but if you find using a pencil leaves pencil marks, try something pointy that isn't a pencil... I mean, it shouldn't be a surprise to you that your pencil is working as designed and drawing lines...